# Proj.db not found when imported SHAPEFILE into Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, shapefile, rgdal, proj

Using "sf" I import a shapefile into Rstudio (last version). Using also last R version. All packages updated.

**espana <- st_read("iberica.shp")**

Reading layer `iberica' from data source` C:\Users\RGis\iberica.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -9.501874 ymin: 36.00013 xmax: 3.322151 ymax: 43.79129
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
**Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_identify: Cannot find proj.db**

I get this message and when I try to get the epsg coordinates, I receive NA

**st_crs(espana)$epsg
[1] NA**

Some help please...

Thanks in advance